# Is it possible to disable wireless networking using the Android SDK or NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, wireless, kiosk

Is it possible to disable wireless networking on an Android device using the Android SDK or NDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to enable / disable the WiFi state, you have to grant the following permission in the application manifest

```
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
```

You can then use the WifiManager to set enable/disable the WIFI.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(enabled);
```

More info on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

For a complete sample, check the following post : http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/turn-wifi-onoff-using.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can disable the wifi programmatically:

1. Retrieve a [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) object from `Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)`
2. Set [setWifiEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled%28boolean%29) to true or false as you wish

Look up for the permission settings. You will probably need to add some in the `AndroidManifest.xml`